# How to change url of ajax function depending the return value of beforesend() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run a function inside `beforesend()` in jquery ajax. Depending on the return value of that function I want to change the URL of ajax request. For an example refer below.

If `myFunction()` returns a value grater than 1, I want to run url1 otherwise I want to run url2. How to achieve that?

`myFunction()` gives a value grater than 1. But always ajax runs the url2.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fname: $('#com').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        myFunction($('#com').val())
    },
    url: (myFunction($('#com').val()) > 1) ? url1 : url2,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            window.location.href = 'index.php?r=site/index';
        } else {
            alert("Already registered email");
        }
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: how about just calling the function for value before ajax call and getting the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
       settings.url ="new Url";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable something like:

```
var urlToSend;
```

and then assign it in `beforeSend`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fname: $('#com').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        urlToSend=myFunction($('#com').val()) > 1 ? url1 : url2;
    },
    url: urlToSend,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            window.location.href = 'index.php?r=site/index';
        } else {
            alert("Already registered email");
        }
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ajax is not working.I think value of urlToSend is lost after calling before send.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fname: $('#com').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        url = myFunction(parseInt($('#com').val())) > 1 ? url1 : url2;
    },
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            window.location.href = 'index.php?r=site/index';
        } else {
            alert("Already registered email");
        }
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```